# Vue Testing - '... .push is not a function'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Im trying to test a method of a component that adds a new entry to an already existing object.

```
addTag: function () {
  this.value[this.field.key].push(this.tag)
  this.tag = ''
}
```

I am just trying to call that method inside my test via

```
    wrapper.setProps({
      field: {
        key: 'tag'
      },
      value: {
        tag: {}
      }
    })
...
    wrapper.vm.addTag()
```

but it throws and error

```
TypeError: this.value[this.field.key].push is not a function
```

Ive set all needed data and props beforehand (field.key and tag), so that's not the problem. running other methods works completly fine, `push` seems to be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `this.value['tag']` is an object, not an array, so there is no `push` method.

Defining it as an array instead would change that:

```js
wrapper.setProps({
  field: {
    key: 'tag'
  },
  value: {
    tag: []
  }
})
```